# Manually initialising cycle2 - slideCount of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-cycle2

I have a site that uses cycle2. The area that the slideshow is in also has the possibility to be loaded in via AJAX. When this happens, the slideshow stops.

As I have read in the documentation for cycle2, this occurs because of the page reload and I need to manually initialise instead of relying on the auto-initialisation of cycle2.

The doc describes it as such:

```
$( '.mySlideshows' ).cycle();
    "In this case you will need to programatically initialize your slideshow by invoking the cycle method as shown above."
```

So I have done this, and have put the invoke method in my AJAX request so that it fires on the load of the AJAX:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("ajaxParent").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    $( '.cycle-slideshow' ).cycle();
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slideCount' of undefined
```

I'm not sure what it's not getting, afterall this should initialise the slideshow and it works BEFORE the AJAX is reloaded.

Here is the slideshow HTML

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
        data-cycle-fx=fade
        data-cycle-timeout=2000
        data-cycle-prev="#prev-venues"
        data-cycle-next="#next-venues"
        data-cycle-caption="#alt-caption-venue"
        data-cycle-caption-template="{{alt}}"
        data-cycle-log="false"
        >
    <!-- the images -->
      <img src="images/data/venues/hocky.png" alt="Hockey Arena">
    <img src="images/data/venues/athletesvilage.png" alt="Athletes Village">
    <img src="images/data/venues/celticpark.png" alt="Celtic Park">
    <img src="images/data/venues/hampden.png" alt="Hampden">
    </div>
```

Comment: have you done a console.log(xmlhttp.responseText) -> undefined normally means that you haven't grabbed an item by correct class / id.